# Parsing a qbytearray from a binary file

Tags: c++, qfile, qbytearray

Im trying to read around 3000 binary files each binary file is written in little endian. I seek to the file offset and read the entire buffer into a qbytearray.

The binary format is int32 stringlength; (4 bytes) string stringname; + 'null'

File example:

```
//09 00 00 00 63 6f 6e 76 65 72 74 65 72 00 05 00 00 00 63 6f 75 6e 74 00
// 9 is the size then string.. then size then string..

QFile file("papers.bin");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    return;

file.seek(file.size() - 266 );

QByteArray binarydata = file.readall();

//09 00 00 00 63 6f 6e 76 65 72 74 65 72 00 05 00 00 00 63 6f 75 6e 74
```

//loop data

How would i loop the data inside the qbytearray?

Comment: Read the first 4 bytes which is the length, then read the _length_ bytes + the NUL terminator which is not included in the string length etc. Where is the problem? What did you try? And why the `file.seek(file.size() - 266 );`? This isn't very clear.

Comment: bool QFileDevice::seek(qint64 pos) just seeks the postion in the file where the string length and stringsize is.. can qfile read.. read a qbytearray once its been readall?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`QDataStream`](https://devdocs.io/qt~5.11/qdatastream) to read chunks:

```cpp
QDataStream stream(binarydata);
stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
while (!stream.atEnd()) {
    qint32 length;
    stream >> length;

    QByteArray buf(length, 0);
    stream.readRawData(buf.data(), length);
    QString str = QString::fromUtf8(buf);
    // do something with str

    stream.skipRawData(1); // Skip the 00 byte
}
```